# Anyway to easily re-extract an interface in VS 2015?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015

Both VS 2015 and ReSharper 9 doesn't seem to like when an interface already exists when you try to extract a new interface from a class. Is there a way for either VS or ReSharper to just update the existing file by adding / updating the missing methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pull Members Up refactoring](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Refactorings__Pull_Members_Up.html) to move members from a derived class to a base class (or interface).

Comment: Perfect. I just tested and it works as expected. Thank you.